# FixedLengthTokenizer - White space at the end of the line

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch and trying to create an application that can read from txt file and generate output to csv.
I am using FixedLengthTokenizer to read the file, but I am having issue with the last column, the value can have value, or will be filled up with white space, but FixedLengthTokenizer doesn't seems to allow this, as I keep getting "Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectLineLengthException: Line is shorter than max range 21"
Any idea what can solve this?

```
FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();

tokenizer.setNames("column1", "column2", "column3");
tokenizer.setColumns(new Range(1, 5), new Range(6, 10), new Range(10, 21));

Sample data:
code1code2description
code3code4           
code5code6           
code7code8test
```

How to resolve IncorrectLineLengthException for white space in last column with FixedLengthTokenizer